# mysql query in two sever on two table

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to write select join query using MySQL in php.

SERVER 1 is 1.2.3.4 SERVER 2 is 1.5.8.3
server 1 database is customars and SERVER 2 database name is sales

I want to write a query that will select rows from  Test Database on 1.2.3.4 and   Test Database on a.b.c.d.

Is it possible?

Comment: When you say a 'cross-server select query', do you mean a JOINed query?

Comment: sorry brother your are correct i want to write join query.  @BenM

Comment: You could either use `FEDERATED` tables or sync the entire database from server2 to server1 for better performance.